# Get all Jquery variables beginning with "blank"

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, targeting

all!  I've come across a dilemma.  I'm creating something of a price-configurator, and basically Jquery is going to be creating a bunch of subtotal variables as the user selects certain options.  All of these variables will have names that begin with `sub-`  At the end of the code, I'd like to be able to write a line that gets each one of the `sub-` variables and adds its value to a grand total.  Is there a way to do this, and if so, how?

Comment: Please show your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not really a way to do this if the variables are tracked separately. If you stored them in an object, you can loop through the object using

```
$.each(myObject, function (key, value) { 
    if (key.indexOf('sub-') === 0) { 
        // to do 
    } 
});
```

You can do this with an array, and use

```
myArray[myArray.length] = value
```

as you are looping through the form. Then loop through the array at the end to get the values you need.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your code or pseudo-code or knowing anything about the scope of your price configurator, is there any reason why you can't create a (relatively) global grand-total variable that is accessible, scope-wise, to every code path that generates a sub- variable; and then add the value of each sub- variable to the grand total as soon as the value of the sub- variable is calculated?